# Which file is the one containing a Quarto presentation?

Tags: r, presentation, quarto

I wrote a quarto presentation in RStudio Cloud. Now I want to share it, but after rendering, many files have been created, including extensions `.html`, `.qmd` and lots of folders.

Which file should I click on to reproduce the presentation in a web browser (I tried html but looks like plain html) and what shoulh I share to allow others to see my presentation?

Comment: Add a photo of your directory (that contains the `qmd` , `html` files along with other folders) with your question. And clicking on the html file should open the presentation actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented by shafee, you need to open the HTML file with a browser to see the presentation.

For sharing your presentation with others you need to share the `.HTML` file and the `*_files` folder.

It may be convenient to make it self-contained: this ensures that all files needed to display the presentation correctly (plots, styles etc.) are included in the HTML so that you just need to share the latter. This is achieved via modification of the `format` YAML options in the `.qmd` file:

```yaml
format:
  revealjs:
    self-contained: true
```

(Make sure to set the indents as shown! More info [here](https://quarto.org/docs/output-formats/html-publishing.html).)

Note that the HTML file can be large if the presentation draws on many files.